# Regex filter numbers divisible by 3

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of comma-separated ids(digits) . And I need to get only these which are divisible by 3.

`Example:
i = "3454353, 4354353, 345352, 2343242, 2343242 ..."`

Comment: regex is useful for matching patterns against strings. Not for doing math. It would be much easier to just split your string by commas and then filter the resulting list on the divisible by 3 condition.

Comment: Please post more information, such as an example input and output.

Comment: I didn't try anything because I couldn't find anything

Comment: [Regex to match binary numbers divisible by 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867279/regular-expression-to-define-some-binary-sequence) could be of interest.

Comment: I'm sure this one is tagged `regex` just by mistake, however it would be interesting to find a regex solution, if it exists.

Comment: @thg435A regex solution isn't that hard to come up with since the sum of the digits of a number divisible by 3 is also divisible by three. You need three states in a DFA, a state for remainder 0, 1, and 2. and remainder 0 is the accept state.

Comment: I also wondered if there's such but as ascii-lime said. Maybe regex is not good at maths

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430556/regular-expression-for-any-number-divisible-by-60-using-c-sharp-net/3694683#3694683

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really mean *digits* (not *numbers*), this is as easy as

```
 re.findall(r'[369]', my_str)
```

For a list of numbers, it's quite easy *without* regular expressions:

```
lst = "55,62,12,72,55"
print [x for x in lst.split(',') if int(x) % 3 == 0]
```

Comment: Doesn't zero belong there?

Comment: +1 to both thg435 for the answer and eumiro since 0 is indeed divisible by any non-zero integer.

Comment: Also you may need to split on `, `  (comma space), not just `,` as per the recent edit to the question.

Comment: Despite the second example isn't regex, it met my needs. 10x

Comment: @Martin, you probably shouldn't use "*10x*", at least math.stackexchange.com, unless you want to confuse people.

Comment: @Martin - A suggestion: as much as I love regular expressions, and I do, this is definitely the better answer, and you should accept it if you can avoid a regex.

Answer (score 17):

Just for the heck of it:

```
reobj = re.compile(
    r"""\b            # Start of number
    (?:               # Either match...
     [0369]+          # a string of digits 0369
    |                 # or
     [147]            # 1, 4 or 7
     (?:              # followed by
      [0369]*[147]    # optional 0369s and one 1, 4 or 7
      [0369]*[258]    # optional 0369s and one 2, 4 or 8
     )*               # zero or more times,
     (?:              # followed by
      [0369]*[258]    # optional 0369s and exactly one 2, 5 or 8
     |                # or
      [0369]*[147]    # two more 1s, 4s or 7s, with optional 0369s in-between.
      [0369]*[147]
     )
    |                 # or the same thing, just the other way around,
     [258]            # this time starting with a 2, 5 or 8
     (?:
      [0369]*[258]
      [0369]*[147]
     )*
     (?:
      [0369]*[147]
     |
      [0369]*[258]
      [0369]*[258]
     )
    )+                # Repeat this as needed
    \b                # until the end of the number.""", 
    re.VERBOSE)
result = reobj.findall(subject)
```

will find all numbers in a string that are divisible by 3.

Comment: that's more accurate answer thanks again, @Tim Pietzcker would you please provide us a bit information of how it works?

Comment: @Martin: I hope you're not going to use that in production code. Regex is not the right tool for this, even if it works. This is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Does not match 222, 555, etc. 555/3=185 . 222/3=74. `[258]` block is never alone.

Comment: @Kobi: My edited version does. But thg435 is right - there's still something missing. See - that's why regex is not the right tool for this. Will need to test a bit more to at least get this correct...

Comment: I've seen one that seems to work (spoiler, I guess): http://www.rubular.com/r/ZcRDblHg8M

Comment: Forgot my source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3694683/7586 (Mark adds some checks for `% 60`, but I removed them) . I have also done it with the .Net stack: http://wp.me/phMG2-4I

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks. I have taken the liberty to use this regex you linked to and comment it here - it's not mine, so I can't take the credit for it (and as I said, I still don't think regexes should be used for this), but that's better than leaving my original (incomplete and incorrect) regex standing here (the old one can be found in the revision history, of course).

Comment: A DFA converts to the slightly simpler regex `([0369]|([147][0369]*[258])|(([258]|[147][0369]*[147])([0369]*|[258][0369]*[147])([147]|[258][0369]*[258])))*`: http://tinyurl.com/7trrs5j

Comment: Paulpro's simplified regex above does not work for all cases, unfortunately. E.G. 390259107 not matched.

Comment: The one in the answer works for too many cases, e.g. 1111 and 2222 *match* and should not

Comment: @MichaelBoger: No, it doesn't - check it out on https://regex101.com/r/ipsFSQ/1

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh, I see where I got confused; the ?: parts are broken onto lines and I thought it was a "match either" rather than "match both in succession', probably due to the comment on line 3.  My apologies!

Answer (score 3):

A hopefully complete version, from reduction of DEA[1]:

```
^([0369]|[147][0369]*[258]|(([258]|[147][0369]*[147])([0369]|[258][0369]*[147])*([147]|[258][0369]*[258])))+$
```

[1:] [Converting Deterministic Finite Automata to Regular Expressions', C. Neumann 2005](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.2597)
NOTE: There is a typo in Fig.4: the transition from `q_j` to itself should read `ce*b` instead of `ce*d`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867279/regular-expression-to-define-some-binary-sequence) i get:

```
i = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 60, 61, 3454353, 4354353, 345352, 2343241, 2343243"

for value in i.split(','):
    result = re.search('^(1(01*0)*1|0)+$', bin(int(value))[2:])
    if result:
        print '{} is divisible by 3'.format(value)
```

But you don't want to use regular expressions for this task.