# Check modulo arithmetics conditions using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a script to parse text files (csv to be precise) and I want to pick lines from files based on each line content. There are a number of string conditions to check, so I surmised regexp is the way to go, but I also need to check a number in a beginning of a line against conditions in modulo arithmetics, so far it's `n%4==k` and `n%2==k`. It seems however that there are only ad hoc solutions. `n%2==k` is pretty straightforward, but to check `n%4==2` I had to devise something like this:

```
r'((^\d*[24680]|^)[26]|^\d*[13579][048])[\s;,].*' # more (unrelated) conditions follow
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to simplify the regexp above? Are there any obvious problems with it?
2. If I want to generalize the script to other modulo conditions (e.g. `n%3==k` or `n%7==k`), is there a feasible way to do it with regexp, or I'd better extract a number from string and write additional code to check such conditions.

Comment: Have you tried `n%\d+==(?:k|\d+)`? It matches `n%(number)==(k or number)`.

Comment: I'm horrified by a thought of having to debug this. Please consider using [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) and converting to integers.

Comment: You appear to have found a hammer, but modulo conditions are *not* nails. Why not just convert these to integers and test their value that way?

Comment: @Blender Sorry if I'm not clear in my description, there is a number in text form in the beginning of a string that I need to check against conditions like (number)%4==2 or (number)%2==1 , there is no text like "n%4==k" in a string.

Comment: Then you'd have to extract those numbers via capturing groups. Regex isn't really the tool for constructing logic like this. It's more appropriate to use regex for extracting the numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess that's what I'll have to do if I need to use other modulo conditions. My idea was, I need to check each line with regexp anyway, so why not check a number in a line with it as well, at least for simple cases.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Thanks for pointing to the csv library.

Comment: You have a problem, you try solve it with regexps - now you have two problems!  http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be more accurate for `n%4==2` (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule)

```
r = r'^[26]$|^\d*[02468][26]$|^\d*[13579][048]$'

# test
for i in xrange(1, 1000):
    m = re.match(r, str(i))
    if i % 4 == 2:
        assert m, [i, i % 4]
    else:
        assert not m, i
```

For `n%3==0` see [Regex filter numbers divisible by 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992279/python-regex-filter-numbers-divisible-by-3).
I'm not aware of any generic solution for `mod n`, in any case it would be an interesting but purely theoretical exercise. In real life, just use ints.

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner. Yes, mod 3 or 7 are more theoretical of course.