# Regex for multiples of 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, unobtrusive-validation

I am not sure if this can be achieved via Regex **Edit Alone**. I need to validate a integer field value for multiples of 10 in my MVC View. Is this achievable via regex alone and unobstrusive validation?

Comment: What's wrong with something like `[0-9]*0`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sometimes answer is right in front of youand is simple :)

Comment: Why don't use the module? 5%10 != 0 and 50%10 == 0 son any multiple of ten will allways have module 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^[0-9]*0$
```

Of course this will allow `0`. If you'd like to ensure that the input is greater than or equal to 10, you can use this:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*0$
```

However, this won't handle numbers expressed in different numeral systems (e.g. ۱۰, which I believe is 10 in [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals)). It would be better to create a [custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) to test the value of the input. A simple implementation would look a bit like this:

```
public class MultipleOf10Attribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return ((int)value) % 10 == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. It's my understanding that multiples of 10 end in 0. Always. (At least in decimal.) So how about

```
^.*0$
```

or if you want to make sure they're all decimal:

```
^\d*0$
```

simple, unless I'm missing something.

As per the comments, matching negative numbers:

```
^-?\d*0$
```

For a more generalized (and totally useless) approach, check out: [Check number divisibility with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403842/check-number-divisibility-with-regular-expressions)

And a cool way to check for primes, again useless [here](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/)

Comment: `asdasdas0` matches that regex

Comment: This will not match negative numbers.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thanks for the tip -- I assumed "integer field" meant that all input would be integral.

Comment: @rogaos you may be right actually, doesn't hurt to make the regex clearer though :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that here is the regex for multiple of 10

```
^\d*\d?((10)|(0))\.?((0)|(00))?$
```

Comment: That seems like a complicated way of doing it.. also OP says "integer field", and you appear to be allowing decimals