# Write a Regular Expression which identifies numbers divisible by 11

Tags: regex, odk

For a study I am doing everyone gets assigned a unique number.
All unique numbers are divisble by 11 (this is done because it makes sequential numbers quite different from each other).

I would ideally like a regex which I can use to check that the number entered in the study_id field is an acceptable value - e.g divisible by 11. 
I will have leading zeroes to a maximum of 5 digits
So:

- 00011 - Acceptable
- 00012 - Not Acceptable
- 13211 - Acceptable
- 13221 - Not Acceptable

Any suggestions gratefully received

Comment: I would be surprised if this was possible to do using a regular expression.

Comment: Similar question, interesting reading: [How do I write a regular expression that matches an IPv4 dotted address?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060522-08/?p=31113)

Comment: It could be possible as there even is a shorthand rule for calculating division with 11, but considering how long the regex for divisible by 3 is, I'd say this is way too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check number divisibility with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403842/check-number-divisibility-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible because there are no textual similarities between numbers that are divisible by `11`. Regex is used for text matching.

For example `000165` is divisible by `11` as is `00011`.

The best way to validate the number is to divide it by 11 and see if there is any remainder. So in Excel you'd do this:

```
=IF(MOD(165, 11) = 0, "VALID", "INVALID")
```

Or C# you'd do something like this

```
bool isValid = 165 % 11 == 0;
```

(**Disclaimer** I'm not familiar with ODK so I can't provide a suitable sample; I've just guessed on the best language to write in)

Comment: This is not true. The set of numbers divisible by eleven (the same is true for any other natural number, obviously) does form a regular language, therefore a regular expression for the language exists. For instance `^((0*1(10*1)*0(0(10*1)*0|1)*0(10*1)*10*)|(0*(1(10*1)*10*)?))$` is a RE testing divisibility of binary numbers by 3. Theoretically (and fairly straightforwardly), you could construct such a RE for any divisibility checking. However, practically, the RE would be _huge_. So, yeah, you don't want to do that, you want to use standard arithmetic instead.